# Multidimensional Arrays to store multiple data types

Tags: java, arrays

I know php a little. and java much little.

I am creating a small application to search a text in a text area and store the result in a array.

The array in PHP will look like this.

```
array(
    "searchedText" => "The text that is searched",
    "positionsFound" => array(12,25,26,......),
    "frequencies" => 23 //This is total words found divided by total words
);
```

But, java does not support array with multiple data types. In the above array, only the second element "positionFound" is of variable length.

Later on I need to iterate through this array and create a file including all above mentioned elements.

Please guide me

Comment: Can I suggest that you take the time to read the Sun Java Tutorial starting with the "New To Java" page - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/newtojava/new2java-141543.html.  In the long term this will save you lots of pain ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does support Objects. You have to define a Class like

```
class MyData {
    String searchedText;
    Set<Integer> positionsFound;
    int frequencies;
}

List<MyData> myDataList = new ArrayList<MyData>();
// OR
MyData[] myDataArray = new MyData[number];
```

And you can use this structure to hold your data.  There are other methods which are helpful such as constructors and toString() and I suggest you use your IDE to generate those.

When writing this data to a file, you might find JSon a natural format to use.

---

I suggest you look at [GSon](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) which is a nice JSon library.

From the [GSon](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) documentation, here is an example

```
class BagOfPrimitives {
  private int value1 = 1;
  private String value2 = "abc";
  private transient int value3 = 3;
  BagOfPrimitives() {
    // no-args constructor
  }
}
```

(Serialization)

```
BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

==> json is {"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}

Note that you can not serialize objects with circular references since that will result in infinite recursion.

(Deserialization)

```
BagOfPrimitives obj2 = gson.fromJson(json, BagOfPrimitives.class);
```

==> obj2 is just like obj

Comment: You should add the outer array would then be similar to `MyData[] myData`.

Comment: Which package is set in? It is giving cannot find symbol error

Comment: @mrN, `java.util.Set` My IDE just finds it for me and adds the import automagically. ;)

Comment: @Peter, Can you tell me the way to store the values in the two ways to have suggested. I am going nuts, trying to figure that out.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? I am using netbeans

Comment: I prefer IntelliJ CE as it tends to be more helpful once you know all its functionality.  However, netbeans should offer quick fix suggestions as well.

Comment: @Peter, please tell me the way to store the data in both ways you suggested.

Comment: @mrN, I only suggested one way JSon, but there are plenty of libraries which do this. One which looks the best is http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ I will add the example from their documentation.